# Placeholder css for just this page

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the color for placeholder texts on a single page but not globally, and am struggling to do so. Currently I am trying to target all placeholders under a parent container. This is a particularly long page, and targeting for each individual element would be unreasonable I think. The concept I've tried to put to use is

```
       .contactform ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
          color: #FFF;
       }

       .contactform :-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
          color: #FFF;  
       }

       .iwacontactform ::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
          color: #FFF;
       }

       .iwacontactform :-ms-input-placeholder {  
          color: #FFF;
       }
```

Comment: Can you change your HTML? Just attach a unique class or id to the `<html>` or `<body>` tags to mark this page and use that to scope to your styles.

Comment: @Zaqx that'd be fine, but how is that different than trying to target all placeholders in the containing div?

Comment: If that containing div is on other pages, then your global styles will apply styles to the placeholders on other pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include a `<style>` tag in the header of this one page with the placeholder styles. Unless you wanted to use the `!important` hack, you would have to make sure the level of specificity is greater than any global css you already have in place.

Comment: I've used the `!important` hack to see if it was being set somewhere else, and did not see pre-existing styles in developer tools, unfortunately i didn't create this site, only making changes. Is the way I have it above supposed to work assuming there aren't styles being set elsewhere that are interfering?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I'm not able to comment above, but targeting through a containing div is the preferred way. But if that containing div is on other pages, you would still want to put the styles in a `<style>` tag on that one page. Or, you could assign a class or id to the body/html as NathanKTC mentioned.

Comment: You got me on the right track, there was another div being created dynamically inside my container but before my placeholders that had these styles being targeted, they took some digging to find but once I included them into the selector they were being overwritten for this page only. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The style for placeholder must be applied to inputs tag. This example could help you: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/s53chL64/)

```
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Hello" />
</form>
```

And CSS:

```
form input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: red;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
form input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: red;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
form input:-moz-placeholder {   /* Older versions of Firefox */
    color: red;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
form input:-ms-input-placeholder { 
    color: red;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```